# Prestashop class cache

Tags: php, caching, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm updating a module I made adding a new field. The changes work locally but when I upload to the FTP and see the website it gives me an error saying that the field is empty. This module I made is completely isolated, there are no overrides, everything is in the modules folder.

I believe it happens due to cache. I cleaned the cache following [this article](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_clear_the_cache_in_prestashop/). I also deleted the `class_index.php` inside the `cache` folder. I also set the advanced parameters > performance to not cache and after it all, I still get the error.

What am I missing? I upload the folder, replace the files and even after that I still get the error message. The version I'm using the 1.6.1.12, locally and remote.

---

**UPDATE**:
The error message:

```
2 errors 
An error occurred while creating an object. adnquota (Unknown column 'message' in 'field list')
Property AdnquotaCategoryModel->id_adnquota is empt
```

Notes: the module works locally with the same version of prestashop (That's why I think is it cache). When uninstalled the module deletes the tables. In the object model class I added the definition and the property, in the form I added the field.

---

UPDATE 2:
I just found the error. It was a typo in the name of the table I deleted when I uninstall. So when installing I would not create the table again with the new field, so the field didn't exist in the DB.

I'm leaving the question here so it may be useful for someone else who might make the same mistake I did.

Comment: where you add new field? please explain details.  you can share any screenshot or something like this.

Comment: Can you please post the exact error here.  Or if possible add screenshot in your question

Comment: @MdKamruzzaman I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: please check if you have missed any hook registered.

Comment: @AndréLuiz Cache wouldn't do that. Something is wrong with your object model or maybe your live website table structure isn't the same as dev. Have you tried to fully reset module in dev version to see if you get any errors?

Comment: @TheDrot I just found the error. It was a typo in the name of the table I deleted when I uninstall. So when installing I would not create the table again with the new field, so the field didn't exist in the DB.

Comment: @AndréLuiz Thought that might be it. I had a similar problem last week I somehow managed to name a column in sql script containing letter `i` but with an apostrophe like in your name :) Took me a while to find the error...